# generate log for command line process from java

Tags: java, cmd

```
Process p1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
String command="cmd.exe /c B:\\BelkAnanlyticsExtract\\batFiles\\HHExtraction02.bat>> logs\\HHExtraction02.log";
```

The log file which is generated is different from the one that is generated when I run this command from the command line.

I would like to generate the same log. Please help me with this.

Comment: and what's the difference?

Comment: If you mean the files are created at different location then you might give absolute path.

Comment: no the path is same. but when executing from java we have the commands but from dos we have the details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the ErrorStream and InputStream from the process instance and redirect it to your logger.

```
process.getErrorStream();
process.getInputStream();
```

Comment: could you please help me with the snippet i am doing for the first time

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it's working for me,

the code tracing the jar file wokring

```
  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"D:\\myprojectpath\\target\" && java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev myjar-0.0.1.jar");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();

       BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
       String line;
       while (true) {
           line = r.readLine();
           if (line == null) { break; }
           System.out.println(line);
       }
        return true;
```